# checking multiple conditions in an if else block

Tags: c#

This seems like it should be simple, but this block of code is not working.

I just need to check and make sure the current race_position is not equal to the total count or not greater than the count or not equal to 0. If it's any of those, then I want to break out of the loop.

I even went through it in the visual studio debugger, and saw when race_position was 0, it still acted as if it was not 0 and never broke out of the loop.

Is there a way to simply this and make it work?

Thanks!

```
if (race_position != race_team.Count || !(race_position > events.Count) || race_position != 0)
{
    next_position = (race_position + 1);
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are `OR`ing (`||`) the conditions together, meaning if one is true, then that block will execute.  You want to `AND` (`&&`) them together, so that they all must be true, or else the loop will exit.

when `race_position` is 0, then `race_position != race_team.Count` is `true`, hence your loop continues.

Comment: oh I see.  So I just use && in place of || and keep everything else the same? Thanks!

Comment: yes, that will work.  The logic could be simplified as well, but that's the cause of your symptoms.

Comment: just curious, how could the logic be simplified?  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!(race_position < race_team.Count &&  race_position > 0))
    break;

next_position = (race_position + 1);
```